# How to change tab bar items after login in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am new in iOS, working on Storyboard and have added Tabbar Controller with navigation controller in it. I want to change the tab bar items after successfully login.

Tab bar items(Before login)-> my contact, search, register, login.

Tab bar items(After login) -> my contact, search, My profile, Logout

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya- No, It works with xib but not working in storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same as without storyboard. Use UITabBarController's methods:

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *viewControllers;
and
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

> Sets the root view controllers of the tab bar controller.
>
> When you assign a new set of view controllers at runtime, the tab bar
>   controller removes all of the old view controllers before installing
>   the new ones. When changing the view controllers, the tab bar
>   controller remembers the view controller object that was previously
>   selected and attempts to reselect it. If the selected view controller
>   is no longer present, it attempts to select the view controller at the
>   same index in the array as the previous selection. If that index is
>   invalid, it selects the view controller at index 0.

To get UITabBarController you can use outlet mechanism or just get it from ViewController with `self.tabBarController`.

Comment: I have one more issue when I'm removing/replacing current view(Login) in the same controller or from My profile controller, its showing
"Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle" error

Comment: @Sujay Not seems that it could be connected with UITabBarController. First of all check that required Nib exists and has appropriate name (by default it should be the same as your UIViewController's class name).

Comment: @Avt- I've checked, Same code is working fine with xib files but not in storyboard.
I've connected all the views to tab bar controller and on ViewDidLoad I'm removing tab items on above condition.

also I tried to create tab bar programmatically in appDelegate with following code-


self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.myContactsController, self.searchController, self.registrationController, self.loginController, nil];


It's giving the same error.

Comment: @Sujay not sure but maybe this one http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 could help you.